# Length of \underbracket with Libertinus Math

Tags: brackets, libertinus

The combination of Libertinus Math and `\underbracket` (provided by `mathtools`) produces unreasonably large brackets if the argument of `\underbracket` becomes too long.

[image: underbracket]

(One can probably also argue that in the second to fourth example the bracket is a bit too short.)

The same output occurs with `\Uunderbracket` (provided by `unicode-math`) instead of `\underbracket`.
The problem also occurs with `\overbracket` and `\Uoverbracket`.

[image]

The problem does not occur with `\underbrace` or `\overbrace` (but one could again argue that some of the braces are too short).

[image]
[image]

It this a problem with Libertinus Math (which I would then report to the developer) or a problem with `mathtools` / `unicode-math` (in which case I don’t know what to do about it)?

---

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrartcl}


\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\begin{document}

\noindent\texttt{underbracket}
\[
    \underbracket{a}
  + \underbracket{ab}
  + \underbracket{abc}
  + \underbracket{abcd}
  + \underbracket{abcde}
  + \underbracket{abcdeh}
  + \underbracket{abcdehi}
  + \underbracket{abcdehik}
\]
\texttt{Uunderbracket}
\[
    \Uunderbracket{a}
  + \Uunderbracket{ab}
  + \Uunderbracket{abc}
  + \Uunderbracket{abcd}
  + \Uunderbracket{abcde}
  + \Uunderbracket{abcdeh}
  + \Uunderbracket{abcdehi}
  + \Uunderbracket{abcdehik}
\]
\noindent\texttt{overbracket}
\[
    \overbracket{a}
  + \overbracket{ab}
  + \overbracket{abc}
  + \overbracket{abcd}
  + \overbracket{abcde}
  + \overbracket{abcdeh}
  + \overbracket{abcdehi}
  + \overbracket{abcdehik}
\]
\texttt{Uoverbracket}
\[
    \Uoverbracket{a}
  + \Uoverbracket{ab}
  + \Uoverbracket{abc}
  + \Uoverbracket{abcd}
  + \Uoverbracket{abcde}
  + \Uoverbracket{abcdeh}
  + \Uoverbracket{abcdehi}
  + \Uoverbracket{abcdehik}
\]
\texttt{underbrace}
\[
    \underbrace{a}
  + \underbrace{ab}
  + \underbrace{abc}
  + \underbrace{abcd}
  + \underbrace{abcde}
  + \underbrace{abcdeh}
  + \underbrace{abcdehi}
  + \underbrace{abcdehik}
\]
\texttt{overbrace}
\[
    \overbrace{a}
  + \overbrace{ab}
  + \overbrace{abc}
  + \overbrace{abcd}
  + \overbrace{abcde}
  + \overbrace{abcdeh}
  + \overbrace{abcdehi}
  + \overbrace{abcdehik}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems a problem specific to Libertinus Math.

Comment: These “large” symbols are pieced together by repeated rules (in the middle). Libertinus Math’s middle rules were rather inconsistently designed (some were too long while some were too short).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was apparently a problem with the Libertinus Math font.
Some [recent changes](https://github.com/alerque/libertinus/commit/1c8858af514c3dec5bcba07bf3e6abebddd709c9) fix the problem, and the output now looks as follows.

[image]